# Can you extend selection of text from the beginning with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: word-processing

Basic selection extension with Shift + `arrow key`:

[image: Basic selection extension with shift + arrow key]

When you select something, you can use shift + `arrow key` to extend your selection at the end.

Can you extend the beginning of selected text?

[image: Can you extend the beginning of selected text?]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you want to extend to the left of the cursor, you can use shift left arrow; to the right you already seem to know shift right arrow. I know of no shortcut key to extend in both directions at once. If I wanted to select that line, I would press Home, then shift + end.

Comment: I was just going to ask the exact same thing. It would be a nice productivity / quality of life trick!

Answer (score 1):

> When you select something, you can use shift + arrow key to extend your selection at the end.
>   Can you extend the beginning of selected text?

Besides selection, you always move the cursor with arrow keys. In your screenshot you've selected the text from left to right, therefore the cursor was at the end of the selection, and you moved that.

If you select from the end to the beginning, then you'll have your cursor at the beginning, so you can move the beginning of the selection.

I'm not aware of a general way to move the cursor within the selection, there might be some tools which supports that behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for [how to the switch the cursor to the start/end of the current selection](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-switch-cursor-to-start-end-of-selection/14551)? This is not a common feature. The [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) editor has a plugin [SelectUntil](https://github.com/xavi-/sublime-selectuntil#readme) that accomplishes this with Alt+Shift+R but this is not part of Windows.

If you have something already selected in Wordpad e.g. and want to expand/shrink both ends of the selection with keyboard/mouse then Shift-Arrow/Shift-Click will adjust only the selection end. For adjusting the selection start you are out of luck. When selecting with the mouse, the selection end is where the mouse is released so highlighting backwards changes which extremity of your selection is adjustable with Shift-Arrow/Shift-Click.

Answer (score -1):

> Can you extend the beginning of selected text?

Unfortunately, if I am not misunderstanding, you can't add characters with a selection as far as I am aware. Selections only highlight existing characters, whether those are normal letters, etc. or invisible characters such as spaces.